# Mysql: Select max count from different id

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, max

I have two table student and exam look like

`student(studentid,lastname,firstname,class)`

`exam(studentid,course,mark,result)`

I need find the best students have mark with 90, 100 in each class.

this is what I need

```
class     studentid  best
K11       K1101       3    
K12       K1203       2
K13       K1305       2
```

this is my first code

```
Select st.class, st.studentid, count(st.mark) as best
From exam e inner join student st on e.studentid = st.studentid
Where e.mark = 90 or e.mark = 100
Group by e.studentid
```

return

```
class     studentid  best
K11       K1101       3
K12       K1201       1
K12       K1203       2
K13       K1305       2
```

so I try another code

```
Select st.class, st.studentid, count(st.mark) as best
From exam e inner join student st on e.studentid = st.studentid
Where e.mark = 90 or e.mark = 100
Group by st.class
Having count(e.mark) = 
       (Select max(count)
        From (Select count(ex.mark) count
              From exam ex
              Where ex.mark = 90 or ex.mark = 100
              Group by ex.studentid) a)
```

and still get wrong answer

```
class     studentid  best
K11       K1101       3
K12       K1201       3
```

**UPDATE DATA**

Sorry about unclear question. I need to find the students in each class have many courses with exact score 90 or 100. This is my data

exam

```
studentid    course   mark result
K1101        DB       100  Pass
K1101        CD       90   Pass
K1101        DIP      95   Pass
K1101        OT       100  Pass
K1102        DB       97   Pass
K1102        CD       65   Pass
K1102        DIP      70   Pass
K1102        OT       44   Fail
K1201        DB       85   Pass
K1201        CD       90   Pass
K1201        DIP      76   Pass
K1201        OT       65   Pass
K1202        DB       69   Pass
K1202        CD       32   Fail
K1202        DIP      57   Pass
K1202        OT       96   Pass
K1203        DB       90   Pass
K1203        CD       87   Pass
K1203        DIP      90   Pass
K1203        OT       91   Pass
K1301        DB       75   Pass
K1301        CD       79   Pass
K1301        DIP      78   Pass
K1301        OT       63   Pass
K1305        DB       90   Pass
K1305        CD       93   Pass
K1305        DIP      100  Pass
K1305        OT       80   Pass
```

In this case, in class K11, student K1101 have 2 courses with 100, one with 90, so I count 3

Comment: Show the source data.

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't it be `e.mark BETWEEN 90 AND 100`. It would make no sense to award student who must have exact score (90, 100), but not between. And can student with id `K1201` be actual have one score 90 or 100?

Comment: can you show some sample data ?

Comment: Just update the data, and yes, I need exact score 90 or 100.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select   st.class, st.studentid, count(mark) as best
From exam e inner join student st on e.studentid = st.studentid
Where e.mark between 90 and 100
and e.mark in (select max(mark) from exam group by studentid)
Group by st.class
```

Comment: so that in class K12, count(mark) will return 3 because it groups all students' mark. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your results don't seem consistent with the phrasing of the question.  You say:  "I need find the best students have mark with 90, 100 in each class."  However, the table only shows one student per class, even thought the count column has three.

If you need to know something per class, then you should be grouping by the class.  If you need to show all students.  Putting these together:

```
Select st.class, group_concat(st.studentid), count(st.mark) as best
From exam e inner join
     student st
     on e.studentid = st.studentid
Where e.mark in (90, 100)
Group by st.class;
```

If you want to count the number of class for a student:

```
Select st.studentid, group_concat(st.class), count(st.mark) as best
From exam e inner join
     student st
     on e.studentid = st.studentid
Where e.mark in (90, 100)
Group by st.studentid;
```

Comment: sorry about my bad question. But this will return count(st.mark) at 3, and it groups all students in class K12